# PyQt5: one signal comes instead of two as per documentation

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.3, signals-slots, pyqt5

I have been reading the section "Connecting Slots By Name" on [this PyQt5 documentation page](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) which basically describes new signals and slots functionality. This piece caught my eye:

> For example the QtGui.QSpinBox class has the following signals:
>
> ```
> void valueChanged(int i);
> void valueChanged(const QString &text);
> ```
>
> When the value of the spin box changes both of these signals will be emitted.

So I sketched up the following script to test this double call behaviour:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QSpinBox

class Test(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.spb = QSpinBox()
        self.spb.valueChanged.connect(self.onValueChanged)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.spb)

    def onValueChanged(self, x):
        print("QSpinBox: value changed! " + str(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Test()
    t.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And it looks to me like only one signal is coming through. What am I missing? Please note that I am a complete `PyQt` noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only connected to one of the two signal overloads.

Since you also didn't specify *which* overload you wanted, a default will be selected - which in this case will be `valueChanged(int)`.

To explicitly select *both* overloads, you would need to do:

```
    self.spb.valueChanged[int].connect(self.onValueChanged)
    self.spb.valueChanged[str].connect(self.onValueChanged)
    ...

def onValueChanged(self, x):
    print("QSpinBox: value changed! ", x, type(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also note that the documentation is talking about slots by name, so you should first add a name to your spinbox.

```
self.spb.setObjectName("spb")
```

Then, connect all the slots:

```
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)
```

And finally create the slot using the `on_widgetName_signalName` form.

```
def on_spb_valueChanged(self, x):
    print("QSpinBox: value changed! " + str(x))
```

It will be called twice now.

Use the `pyqtSlot` decorator to indicate which signal you want to receive.

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def on_spb_valueChanged(self, x):
```

Or...

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def on_spb_valueChanged(self, x):
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But the key point is that the `pyqtSlot` decorator must be used to specify which overload is needed. It's almost always a bug to get multiple signals - see [Why is PyQt Executing my actions 3 times?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22852094/984421), for instance (and there are probably several other SO questions in a similar vein).

Comment: @ekhumoro I agree, but the title says "PyQt5: one signal comes instead of two as per documentation". Here's how to receive two signals instead of one, as the documentation explains. I'm just adding some information.

Comment: I think the OP was just testing to see what actually happens. Anyway, I only meant to suggest you might add a little bit about `pyqtSlot`, as this would then complement my answer quite nicely (i.e. showing two different ways to achieve the same thing).